# Div with position absolute not moving where it shoud (understanding positioning css)

Tags: html, css

I am trying to understand css positioning. For what I have read, when an element is set to `position: absolute`, it's then positioned in relation to the first parent element it has that doesn't have `position: static`.

So I have created three colored divs and moved the second 50px from the left. Then I have set the position to absolute on the third, and written left: 50px; also.

I don't understand then why my third dive, isn't moved 100 px from the left (50 that is moved the second one + 50 that this one should move from where the second it is)

Here is a fiddle with it: https://jsfiddle.net/kbww4w7v/

Why am I missing? Thanks!

(P.S. Don't tell me to Google it. I have. I have read every single tutorial or post about positioning that appeared in Google page 1 or 2 and still do not understand it)

Answer (score 1):

The third div isn't a child of the other divs. They need to be nested:

```
<div id="grandad">
    <div id="father">
        <div id="element"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The way they currently are, they are considered siblings, and don't inherit anything from each other.

Comment: Aaaah, okay, sorry! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I looked your code and what you have aren't parents/siblins but all your divs are at same level.
Try your css with this:

```
<div id="grandad">
  <div id="father">
     <div id="element"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

That only works when they are nested.

```
<div id="grandad">
  <div id="father">
    <div id="element"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[See this updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kbww4w7v/2/)

Answer (score 0):

absolutely positioned elements are no longer within the flow of the dom tree, they only truly respect the position of a relative element.

```css
/* DEMO */
body {margin: 0;}
div {
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px 0 #111;
}

/* STYLES */
.relative {
  position: relative;
  width: 33%;
  background: red;
}
.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  left: 25%;
  width: 50%;
  background: gold;
}
```

```html
<div class="relative">
 <div class="absolute"></div>
</div>
<div class="relative">
 <div class="absolute"></div>
</div>
<div class="relative">
 <div class="absolute"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference between the 3 main position are this:

> static: the element is considered in the DOM flow so it retain it's
> position and dimension and is not affected by position transform.
>
> relative: the element is considered in the DOM flow but it's subject to position transform based on itself position (in the example the margin space is mantain and it occupy space in the body, but only it's original space, infact the #mother element is not moved but #father overlap it)
>
> absolute: the element is considered out of the DOM flow and it don't take space, it's subject to position transform based on the first non-static element or the window if no other element is found, it can go over other elements.

You can see in the below example the 3 cases:

```
\body\
<div id="grandad"></div>
<div id="father"></div><div id="mother"></div>
<div id="element"></div>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kbww4w7v/8/)